# Array CountIf Substitute - Count(Match())

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, countif

### Core Question

How can I perform repeated `CountIf()`s on a range as efficiently (performance-wise) as possible?

### Concerns in Detail

**Range to Array**

Since each read/write to a spreadsheet results in slower VBA code, it is advisable to do so as few times as possible. Normally, if someone is repeatedly reading/writing to a range, he or she should first save that range to an array, perform the operations to the array, and then do a final read or write to the spreadsheet if necessary.

**Example Values and Code**

[image: Example Values]

How can I use perform `CountIf()`s on the range of `A2:A11` above to calculate the count of each value and write them to `D2:D7`? I would expect the below code to work:

```
Sub M1ArrayCount()

Dim arrNumbers() As Variant
Dim Long1 As Long
Dim Loop1 As Long

arrNumbers() = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A11").Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For Loop1 = 1 To 6
        .Cells(Loop1 + 1, 4).Value = Application.CountIf(arrNumbers(), Loop1)
    Next Loop1
End With

End Sub
```

**CountIf() Doesn't Work with Arrays**

However, because `Application.CountIf()` only works with ranges and not arrays, `D2:D7` all show `#VALUE!` errors after running the above code. A substitute must be found.

Comment: The answer to this will depend on how big your data set is.  How many rows in"Range To Test" and how many rows in "Values"?

Comment: That's true - I intend this answer for large data sets and didn't specifically say so. My own data set was 90,000 rows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solution - Count(Match())

The solution we are looking for is:

`Application.Count(Application.Match(SavedArray(), Array([lookup_value]), 0))`

What? How does that work?
---
How can a function that normally returns a row number be paired with an array and count to return the correct answer? How can you count row numbers?

**Explanation of Mechanics**

With many thanks to @Jeeped, here's how it works:

It's an undocumented feature of `Match(lookup value, lookup array, 0)` that if you put an array as the lookup value, it will `Match()` each value in the array you entered against the lookup array. Thus, for the above example, for `Loop = 1`, it will become:

`{match(A2, Array("1"), 0),match(A3, Array("1"), 0), ... match(A11, Array("1"), 0)}`

Then, per @Jeeped:

> Each match will either return a number or an error. The `Count()` function counts numbers, not errors. So you get a count of whether any of the values in `A1:A11` match `Loop1`.

**Final Code and Values**

```
Sub M1ArrayCount()

Dim arrNumbers() As Variant
Dim Long1 As Long
Dim Loop1 As Long

arrNumbers() = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A11").Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For Loop1 = 1 To 6
        .Cells(Loop1 + 1, 4).Value = Application.Count(Application.Match(arrNumbers(), Array(Loop1), 0))
    Next Loop1
End With

End Sub
```

[image: Final Results]

References
---
[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507501/vba-why-does-application-countif-return-an-array-or-error-424#comment45355497_28507501)

[This answer](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/739653-countif-visual-basic-applications-array-without-loop.html#post3635486)

> **Question**
>
> > Example:
> >
> > ```
> > myarray = array("First","Second","Second","Third","Fourth")
> > ```
> >
> > then what would the `countif(myarray,"second")` syntax be? (the result
> > should equal 2 counts)
>
> **Answer**
>
> > Try also:
> >
> > ```
> > MsgBox Application.Count(Application.Match(myArray, Array("Second"), 0))
> > ```

[This chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30481710#30481710)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30485994#30485994
Also from @Jeeped: "I finally found some time to bench test that method a little more thoroughly and I have found a limitation. Using the parameters backwards limits the array as the lookup_value to 255 elements. This makes it prohibitive to use as an array-based substitution to countif in large blocks of data."

Comment: Nice; came across your interesting approach by chance +1)

Comment: Beautiful solution. If you get an error, makes sure you are using `Application.Match` and **not** `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`. The former won't work, because it throws a VBA error for the none-matches as I found out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27302888/12418842

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rowin as integer 'this is a counter for the row index
For rowin = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & rowin).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Range("C" & rowin))
Next
```